# Perfmon performance counters on WAMP

Tags: php, performance, windows

I work on an WordPress site for a business. I'm using WAMP: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, sp 1, 64-bit. Apache version 2.4 MySql version 5.6.9 PHP version 5.4.13 8 GB RAM Intel Xeon CPU 2.93GHz (4 processors)

We're seeing intermittent high CPU usage on our production servers. We have monitors setup to email us if CPU usage remains > 80% for more than 10 minutes and this happens 3-4 times per week.

Ideally, I'd attach a PHP performance profiler, but don't want to do that in prod because I'm afraid it would cause performance problems.

My question is this: are there any Windows perfmon performance counters that could help us diagnose the cause of the high CPU usage? I suspect the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask. I realize there are CPU performance counters,but I'm wondering if there's anything PHP specific.

I strongly suspect that the problem is WordPress/PHP. In the past, I've decreased the CPU usage significantly on the server by configuring Apache to handle all requests that it is capable of handling (.js, css, images, etc). Thanks.

Comment: Are you using WAMP on a production server?!

Comment: Yes. It was not my decision. Although, I've spoken to a PHP expert and author who said that he's seen WordPress sites running on Windows that performed fine.

Comment: There's a difference between running on WordPress and running on WAMP though, not all Windows hosted sites run via a WAMP/XAMPP developer environment, e.g. IIS, vagrant even

Comment: I just mean I'm running Windows, Apache, MySQL, and PHP. Everything was installed separately, we're not using any bundled software packages.